# Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch while clicking on UIButtons multiple times

Tags: ios

let me explain you whole scenario:

I'm making the audio record & audio player 
When I started recording audio.And I starts to click on pause and stop button multiple times like crazy kid and sometimes buttons stop working and got that error.

please help me out if anyone faces that issue once or resolve it

thanks in advance

Comment: why not keep one disabled, eg : if the audio is already playing keep play button disabled, and if its not keep stop button diabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you could prevent the user from pressing a button repeatedly or too fast by disabling the button for a short period of time every time the button is pressed.

For example, disable the button for 2 seconds:

```
func pressButton() {
    button.isEnabled = false
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(enableButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func enableButton() {
    self.buttonTest.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Turns out that the way I was adding my views inside th view was the main cause of the issue. My apologies!